# Predicating the HOME and WORK location by VESPA

Tags: bigdata, vespa

It is one of the use case of my application. I am feeding location details(latitude, longitude, time) at every 5 minutes to VESPA. How VESPA can predicate the HOME and WORK address on the basis of data I fed into it? Is it possible in VESPA? If YES, How should I write the application for it or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'd need to train a ml model for this.
Vespa can not help you with that, but it can execute those models query time if you need that (which seems unlikely to me since these predictions only change when the addresses (of users I assume) change).

Comment: Can I achieve my use case using spark application?

Comment: You can achieve it e.g by running Keras or Tensorflow on your laptop.